# Solve $x^{2k}+(x-2)^{2k}=2k$ with $k\in \mathbb N$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}^+$

Tags: number-theory

> Solve $x^{2k}+(x-2)^{2k}=2k$  with $k\in \mathbb N$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}^+$.

I have no idea how to solve this, I just can find one solution, $x=k=1$.

Answer (score 2):

Assume $k\ge2$. At $x=0$, and at $x=2$, the left side is bigger than the right. At $x=1$, the right side is bigger than the left. It follows that there is a solution with $0\lt x\lt1$, and another solution with $1\lt x\lt2$.

For $k=2$ it's a quartic equation, and there is a formula for solving those (a websearch for "quartic equation" will undoubtedly turn it up). For $k\ge3$ it's an equation of degree $6$ or higher, and it is unlikely that the solutions can be expressed in terms of integers, arithmetical operations, extractions of $n$th roots (or exponentials, logarithms, trig & inverse trig functions). You can get as close to a solution as you like by numerical methods. If you know some Calculus, there's Newton's Method.

Comment: Hey! If your two solutions were between $0<x<1$ and $1<x<2$ , the $LHS$ won't be a natural number. Did you notice that?

Comment: @Inceptio Why do you say that?  Neither term on the LHS will individually be a natural number, but there's nothing preventing their sum from being one...

Comment: Well then, got any example to prove that?

Comment: @Inceptio, I have something much better than an example, I have a theorem, the Intermediate Value Theorem. Let's take $k=3$, and let $f(x)=x^6+(x-2)^6-6$. Then $f$ is continuous, $f(0)\gt0$, $f(1)\lt0$, and $f(2)\gt0$, so, by the Intermediate Value Theorem, there is a number $a$, $0\lt a\lt1$, and a number $b$, $1\lt b\lt2$, such that $f(a)=f(b)=0$.